# Google locations automatic is not working in my php page

Tags: php, forms, api, google-api

I am using google automatic location api but it is not showing on the page..Can you guys figure out whats wrong in the code.

My script is :

```
<script>
        function init() {
            var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
            var input2 = document.getElementById('locationTextField2');

             var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
             var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2);

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
    </script>
```

My html code is this :

```
     <input type="text" id="locationTextField" placeholder="Source Location"/>
       <input type="text" id="locationTextField2" placeholder="Destination Location"/>
```

Comment: you mean to say search location from `places` libraries autocomplete ?

Comment: yes i am using places libraries

Answer (score 0):

Please load your script with valid api key in your site,

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

**Here is example (without api key for demo only):**

```js
function initialize() {
  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('source')), {
    types: ['geocode']
  });
   new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('dest')), {
    types: ['geocode']
  });
  
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&dummy=.js"></script>

<input id="source" name="source" value="" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Source" />
<input id="dest" name="dest" value="" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Destincation" />
```

Comment: Hy.....the "pac-container pac-logo" classes is coming but after footer..due to which it is not showing on the page

Comment: @varsha not really got, what you said, whether above example is working for you

Comment: did you use valid api keys ?

Comment: hy @3161993 i resolved my console issues bt still it is not working